# how to close a dialogbox without blocking ui

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to close a jquery dialogbox without blocking the UI or reloading the page.
On closing a jquery dialog like this:

```
buttons: {
   'Close': function () {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.ui-dialog').remove();
       $('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
   }
```

the dialog gets hideen but,the UI behind gets blocked. hence i cant click on other links..
Also tried,

```
buttons: {
    'Close': function () {
        $('#quickfillDialog').dialog('close');
    }
```

that also doesn't solve the issue. Please suggest!!

Comment: in close function simply try $(this).close() will close dialog box

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
buttons: {
 'Close': function () {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
```

go through the documentation...

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation